# adjustment of Comparing byDate from 2 different files

Tags: r, compare

I have a data: datagar.csv

```
       Date     Time   Open   High    Low  Close
1 06.08.1993 00:00:00 0.0116 0.0116 0.0116 0.0116
2 09.08.1993 00:00:00 0.0116 0.0116 0.0116 0.0116
3 10.08.1993 00:00:00 0.0117 0.0117 0.0117 0.0117
4 11.08.1993 00:00:00 0.0117 0.0117 0.0117 0.0117
5 12.08.1993 00:00:00 0.0117 0.0117 0.0117 0.0117
6 13.08.1993 00:00:00 0.0117 0.0117 0.0117 0.0117
```

I have a other data: datagar1.csv

```
        Date     Time Open High Low Close
1 19.03.1993 00:00:00   56   57  56    56
2 22.03.1993 00:00:00   56   57  56    57
3 29.03.1993 00:00:00   57   58  57    58
4 30.03.1993 00:00:00   58   59  58    59
5 31.03.1993 00:00:00   59   60  59    59
6 01.04.1993 00:00:00   59   61  59    61
```

and I compare 2 different file by Date,

compare data

```
fdatabak <- datagar[!datagar$Date %in% datagar1$Date,]
head(fdatabak)
          Date     Time   Open   High    Low  Close
1364 20.03.1999 00:00:00 0.3657 0.3659 0.3655 0.3657
1365 21.03.1999 00:00:00 0.3657 0.3659 0.3655 0.3657
1371 27.03.1999 00:00:00 0.3736 0.3738 0.3733 0.3736
1372 28.03.1999 00:00:00 0.3736 0.3738 0.3733 0.3736
1373 29.03.1999 00:00:00 0.3736 0.3744 0.3716 0.3739
1374 30.03.1999 00:00:00 0.3739 0.3744 0.3712 0.3728
```

and now I have a compare data name is fdatabak.

now i want to remove fdatabak from inside datagar.csv.
remove index number 1364,1365,1371,1372,1373,..... from datagar.csv.
How can i do it?

Comment: Perhaps you can use `anti_join` from `dplyr`

Comment: Perhaps `x.csv <- x.csv[!(fdata$Date %in% x.csv$Date),]`.  If `x.csv` is actually a list and not a data frame then use `lapply`.

Comment: anti_join is same as this code. fdatabak <-(!datagar$Date %in% datagar1$Date)
fdata <- datagar[fdatabak,]
head(fdata)   x.csv has got all Date.I want to remove compare list data from x.csv.

Comment: okay, then what is your expected output?

Comment: > a<-anti_join(datagar,datagar1, by="Date")
> head(a)
        Date     Time   Open   High    Low  Close
1 20.03.1999 00:00:00 0.3657 0.3659 0.3655 0.3657

> fdatabak <-(!datagar$Date %in% datagar1$Date)
> fdata <- datagar[fdatabak,]
> head(fdata)
           Date     Time   Open   High    Low  Close
1364 20.03.1999 00:00:00 0.3657 0.3659 0.3655 0.3657
> Thet are same.Its ok.But problem is different.

Comment: Why not use merge: `fdatabak1 <- merge(datagar, datagar1, by="Date")[c(1:6)]`? This will remove any records that the two dfs do not share.